# Clear content of one cell if the value changes in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear content in cell B8 if the value in cell A8 is changed. The trick here is that the value in cell A8 is based on a formula which changes on selecting option buttons. Hence, worksheet_Change function will not work.
I am trying to use the `worksheet_calculate` to solve the issue but the below code is throwing error

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Target As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A8")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B8").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The Calculate event doesn't have a `Target`-parameter, it is triggered when Excel thinks a recalculation is needed, but only once per recalculation. Your `target`-variable is `Nothing` and therefore `Intersect` will fail.

Comment: Assign a macro to the option buttons instead - then you can have the code run only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

in the worksheet module

```
Public oldval

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
oldval = Me.Range("A8").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Me.Range("A8").Value <> oldval Then
            Me.Range("B8").ClearContents
    End If
    oldval = Me.Range("A8").Value
End Sub
```